# Правильная выборка

Tags: sqlite

Делаю социальную сеть и там есть новости где будут записи от людей на которых я подписан. Как получить только 3 записи от одного пользователя SQL... Здесь нужен вложенный sql, а как сделать не знаю

Comment: Как обычно - ROW_NUMBER() в CTE.

Comment: А как использовать

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особое внимание пунктам 5 и 3.